How to solve this duplicate lines?
I have a query that includes two WITH clauses. The first one, 'feriados', returns every day between the start date and end date from a row in a table named 'holidays'. A holiday may start and end on the same day or have different start and end dates. The second clause defines a function named 'data_distinta', which determines whether a day is a valid work day or not. A valid work day is defined as a day that is neither a weekend nor a holiday (being a holiday is filtered by the 'feriados' function). When it's a valid work day, the function returns 1; otherwise, it returns 0.
The issue I'm encountering is that the final result is showing two identical days with opposite values for 'valid work day'.
I'm unable to create a new table to represent the calendar, and the existing calendar table only includes holidays.
WITH RECURSIVE feriados AS 
(
    SELECT begin_date AS dateValue, entities_id AS id
    FROM  holidays
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(dateValue, INTERVAL 1 DAY), id AS id
    FROM feriados
    WHERE DATE_ADD(dateValue, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= (SELECT end_date FROM  holidays WHERE DATE_ADD(dateValue, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date)
),

data_distinta AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE( tickets.date) AS data, 
    
    (CASE
            WHEN WEEKDAY( tickets.date)>=5 THEN 0
            WHEN WEEKDAY( tickets.date)<5 AND DATE( tickets.date) NOT LIKE feriados.dateValue THEN 1
            WHEN DATE( tickets.date) LIKE feriados.dateValue THEN 0 

    END
    ) AS validWorkDay
    
    FROM  tickets
    LEFT JOIN  entities
        ON ( tickets.entities_id =  entities.id)
    LEFT JOIN  calendars
        ON ( calendars.entities_id =  entities.id)
    LEFT JOIN  calendars_holidays
        ON ( calendars.id =  calendars_holidays.calendars_id)
    LEFT JOIN  holidays
        ON ( holidays.id =  calendars_holidays.holidays_id)
    JOIN feriados)
SELECT data_distinta.data, data_distinta.validWorkDay
FROM data_distinta
WHERE data_distinta.data >= '05/01/2024'

this is the code I have
I'm expecting

but I'm getting


You have no ON condition when you join with feriados. So it's going to create a full cross product with all its rows.

Remember that DISTINCT doesn't apply to just one column, it applies to the entire SELECT list. So you'll get both combinations of the validWorkDay.

Why are you using LIKE instead of = when comparing with feriados.dateValue? LIKE is for matching wildcard patterns.

There's no need for the recursive CTE. Just use a LEFT JOIN with the holidays table, testing whether the ticket date is within the holiday's date range. If there's a match, then the ticket date is during a holiday.
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(t.date) AS data, 
                CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(t.date) >= 5 THEN 0
                     WHEN h.id IS NULL THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                END AS validWorkDay
FROM tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN holidays AS h ON t.date BETWEEN h.begin_date AND h.end_date
WHERE t.date >= '2024-05-01'

I'm not sure why you joined with all the other tables, you never use anything from them.

Thank you for you feedback Barmar, I was using the other tables while trying to implement another logic and just forgot them there, already removed, but still while using your solution I got the same result as the second image but without the last row

Can you provide input data in text that can be copy-pasted into a db-fiddle?

I cant put it in the comments section because is too long, where can i provide the input data?

Edit it into the question. Or create a db-fiddle and put a link into the question.

[https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBmoXD9WhMrCn3357rvPGm/1]

I'm not sure what's going on, but when I click that link it redirects to the main db-fiddle.com page.

sorry im new using this and in mysql coding
try that one [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cButAaD7j1hw498SvwkaRp/0]

That also redirects. Make sure you didn't select "Private fiddle".

found the problem, the link was counting the ']'
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cButAaD7j1hw498SvwkaRp/0

I ran my query in your fiddle. I got one row for each date from 2024-05-01 through 2024-05-08. The valid days are 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, which seems correct.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cButAaD7j1hw498SvwkaRp/1

I found the issue. It seems to have been related to the timestamp conversion. Thank you very much for your attention and patience.
